# How to get the value of comments after setState on first render?

Tags: react-native

I'm having this problem where in the first render of this page the value of comments doesn't get updated, but when I go back and re-enter this screen it gets updated. I know useState is asynchronous and probably it is what is causing my problem. I only started with react native one week ago and don't know how I can solve this issue. Here is my code:

```
function Comment(props) {
    const [comments, setComments] = useState([])
    const [text, setText] = useState("")

    const textInput = React.createRef();


    const retrieveComments = () => {
        firebase.firestore()
        .collection("posts")
        .doc(props.route.params.uid)
        .collection("userPosts")
        .doc(props.route.params.postId)
        .collection("comments")
        .orderBy("creation","desc")
        .get()
        .then((snapshot)=>{
            let comments= snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                const data = doc.data()
                const id = doc.id;
                return {id, ...data}
            })
            for(let i=0;i<comments.length;i++){
                if(comments[i].hasOwnProperty("user")){
                    continue
                }
                const user = props.users.find(x => x.uid === comments[i].creator)
                if(user == undefined){
                    props.fetchUsersData(comments[i].creator, false)
                }else{
                    comments[i].user = user
                }
            }
            setComments(comments)
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        retrieveComments()
    },[]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(comments)
    },[comments.length])



    const onCommentSend = () => {
        firebase.firestore()
        .collection("posts")
        .doc(props.route.params.uid)
        .collection("userPosts")
        .doc(props.route.params.postId)
        .collection("comments")
        .add({
            creator: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
            text,
            creation: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
        })
        .then(retrieveComments)
        setText("")
        textInput.current.clear()
    }
    

    return (
        <View style={{flex:1}}> 
            <FlatList   
                numColumns={1}
                horizontal={false}
                data={comments}
                renderItem={({item})=> (
                    <View>
                            {item.user !== undefined && item.creation!==null ?
                                <View style={{marginHorizontal:10, marginVertical:5}}>
                                    <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}
                                    onPress={()=>props.navigation.navigate('Profile',{uid: item.user.uid})}>{item.user.name}</Text>
                                    <Text>{item.text}</Text>
                                    <TimeAgo style={{color:'grey'}}dateTo={item.creation.toDate()}/>
                                </View>
                            :null}
                        <View
                        style={{
                            borderBottomColor: 'silver',
                            borderBottomWidth: 1,
                        }}/>
                    </View>
                )}
            />
            <KeyboardAvoidingView enabled behavior={Platform.select({android: undefined, ios: 'padding'})} keyboardVerticalOffset={64} >
                <View style={{justifyContent:'flex-end', flexDirection:'row'}} behavior="height">
                    <TextInput
                        style={{flex:1}}
                        placeholder="Write a comment..."
                        onChangeText={(text)=> setText(text)}
                        theme={{colors: {text: 'black', primary: 'black'}}}
                        ref={textInput}
                    />
                    <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={()=>{onCommentSend()}}
                    style={{justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center', flex:1, backgroundColor:'black'}}>
                        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="send-circle-outline" color='white' size={40}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </View>
    )
}


const mapStateToProps = (store) => ({
    users: store.usersState.users
})
const mapDispatchProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({ fetchUsersData }, dispatch);


export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchProps)(Comment);
```

P.S.: When I put that second useEffect it logs correctly, and I am out of ideas to solve this.

Thanks for your attention

Comment: You could try to use the `extraData` property of FlatList and set it like `extraData={comments}`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @dianaqqq but it is still not working :(

Comment: What I might try after that is to set `key={comments.length}`. (However, I would recommend you to use the redux flow to make that call and manage the state)

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to pass this to redux, everything I do is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're using redux for state management, retrieveComments function should be implemented with redux middleware like redux-saga or redux-thunk. and your component should receive comments as props;